# Best Way to Import External Python Project

Tags: python

The project I am working on essentially benchmarks certain aspects of various external python projects. This is easy to do for "official" or "well-supported" projects which allow installing as a module. However, I now need to extend this to cases where the projects are messy or have minimal support and were never expected to be used as modules.

My code needs to import certain classes from these projects. These projects often assume that they are the main piece of code, e.g. if they have a subfolder called "utils" they assume they can just `import utils` and go about their business. There's a lot of these imports so it's not really feasible to change them all.

Making as few changes as possible to the 3rd party projects, whats the best way to import code from them?

Comment: There is honestly no good way that wasn't prone to breaking at some point. What sort of benchmarking are you doing? Would it be possible to refactor your benchmark code to be able to be installed as a module instead?

Comment: Are these projects on your PYTHONPATH? If so, are you not able to import them already?

Comment: @AKX I think making my project the installable module is probably the right way, I'm checking if that works

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all folders are proper Python packages so imports don't fail e.g. create each of the required `__init__.py` files, then write a `setup.py` file to bundle them as a library ([more information here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)).

Install the library wherever you want (virtualenv recommended) using `pip install path_to_project_folder`.

Then import them using the name you've chosen in your setup script, and you should be able to use them almost as they are, since the local imports will work in the package namespace.

Comment: I'm currently having some trouble with this, for example if I have a package that I installed called `cb` and one of the modules has `import model` where `model` is in the root directory of the package and all the folders have `__init__.py` in them, I get an error unless  I replace it with `import cb.model`